# Converting str items in a dictionary to int and converting datetime.datetime variable to int

Tags: python, dictionary, type-conversion, epoch

I know have this for loop that looks like this:

```
for i in my_dict[hostname]:
    try:
        if i == '':
            except ValueError:
                pass
            i = int(i)
            print(type(i))
```

It is giving me a syntax error and im unsure where or why.

Comment: This dictionary is invalid. Either you miss other keys or the scores should be a list.

Comment: `my_dict['scores'] = [int(score) for score in my_dict['scores']` is a one-liner if 'scores' is a list. As for datetime, do `d.timestamp()`.

Comment: for i in my_dict[hostname]:
    try:
        if i == '':
            except ValueError:
                pass
            i = int(i)
            print(type(i))

There is an error In this case and I am unsure what it is.

Comment: This is something completely different from what you posted in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I really understand your purpose, but converting a string of an int is straight-forward in Python :

```
>>> s = '123'
>>> int(s)
123
```

To convert a datetime to an int, you can convert it to a `timestamp` and then to an `int`:

```
timestamp = datetime.timestamp(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp is already a number that you can do operations on:

```
>>> d.timestamp()
1562855175.285529
>>> d.timestamp() - 1
1562855174.285529
```

Like @EuclidianHike said, you can easily convert str to int with `int("str")`

Answer (score 0):

Make a 2nd list containing the values of 'scores' but in integer form by doing:

```
int_scores = []

for i in my_dict['scores']:

int_s = int(i)

int_scores.append(int_s) #Add indention as I cannot do it here on stackoverflow
```